# ruby-lsp with rbenv failing to execute

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ruby-lsp

I'm having a problem with installing and trying to use ruby-lsp.

I think I followed the correct steps, but keep getting an error:

1. Be sure I have selected the correct ruby version:

```
❯ rbenv versions
  system
  2.7.4
  3.1.3
* 3.1.4 (set by /Users/myuser/.rbenv/version)
  3.2.1
  3.2.2
```

2. Install the gem:

```
❯ gem install ruby-lsp
Successfully installed ruby-lsp-0.8.0
Ignoring debug-1.7.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine debug --version 1.7.2
Parsing documentation for ruby-lsp-0.8.0
Done installing documentation for ruby-lsp after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

3. Be sure it's listed:

```
❯ gem list ruby-lsp

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

ruby-lsp (0.8.0, 0.7.6, 0.4.4)
```

4. Rehash, just in case (`rbenv rehash`)
5. Run:

```
❯ ruby-lsp
rbenv: ruby-lsp: command not found

The `ruby-lsp' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  3.2.2
```

I don't get why it's present in only one version of Ruby.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply a missing setting: from a previous installation I had no Gem bin path in the `PATH` variable, so my problem was fixed by adding this to the `.bashrc` file:

```bash
# $GEM_HOME already defined
export PATH=$PATH:$GEM_HOME/bin
```